# Looping through a JSON string

Tags: php, loops, foreach, json

I am trying to loop through a JSON string using a `foreach()`. However I keep getting the following error:

```
"Notice: Trying to get property of non-object".
```

The strange part is that when I copy and paste the JSON string and then run the `foreach()`, it work fine. Just to provide some detail, I am using the Best-Buy API.

Since this seemed to work fine for everyone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543389/how-to-decode-a-json-string) is it possible there is something wrong with the data that best buy is feeding me?

Please help, I have tried everything!

**UPDATE** sorry for not posting code. here it is:

```
$info = json_decode($test, true); 
function tagGen($info){
foreach($info as $key => $value){
 }
```

Comment: A code sample would be incredibly useful, as we have no idea whether you have a typo or a deeper issue. I'll take a stab at an answer anyways...

Answer (score 1):

As you have not posted the code so we can just think that you have a string jason encoded. My dear json encoded string is some thing which is some sort of javascript form. And foreach is a php loop. So if you have a json encoded string and you want to use it in foreach loop you have to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function for that.

When you will apply json_decode you will be having a string From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type.
>
> Values true, false and null (case-insensitive) are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively.
>
> NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.

For some example code.

```
$str=json_decode($yourjson);
foreach($str as $key=>$value)
{}
```

Comment: It seems that as long as the Json is in a variable I get this error. When I put it through my foreach() as a string, after doing a print_r it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably not using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on the JSON string. Take a look at how I would do this:

```
$json = "somejsonstring";
$json_array = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_array as $element) {
   echo $element['some key'];
}
```

Note the "true" second parameter given to the json_decode method. That returns an associative array rather than a standard PHP object. Makes it a lot easier to work with in foreach loops.

Hope that helps, although your question should really include a code sample.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using json_decode, here it is taken straight from the program. I am tearing my hair out.                                                            $test = curl_exec($curl_object);  
 curl_close($curl_object);

 $info = json_decode($test, true);

Answer (score 0):

Print your json string somewhere you can copy it and then check if it is valid using this tool: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/