# How to decode this array format?

Tags: php, output, minecraft

I am getting this response from an API:

> {"players":224

Is there something simple I can do to condense it into 224, the number only? Thanks, any help would be much appreciated!

Code:

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.iamphoenix.me/players/?server_ip=play.meloncraft.com&clean=true');
$array = explode(',', $data);
echo $array[0];
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure that string doesn't have a closing brace?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode a JSON String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543389/how-to-decode-a-json-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$data` is a JSON string, you need to decode it with [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) rather than just split it with [explode](http://php.net/explode). However, [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) will normally return an object. If you want it to return an associative array, use `true` as the second argument:

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('http://api.iamphoenix.me/players/?server_ip=play.meloncraft.com&clean=true');
$array = json_decode($data, true);
echo $array["players"]; // will output "214"
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol ye that is JSON,

Search it up if you're intrested.
Anyway:

```
json_decode($data);
```

This will convert it into a php array.

Answer (score 0):

Just use: **json_decode** on the result, and see what it will give You :)

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving data in JSON format. You can decode it and extract the data you want like this:

```
$myData = json_decode($data);
$playerCount = $myData['players'];    // 224
```