# Looping through a JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to loop through a JSON that I post to my PHP backend. The JSON looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "number":"5613106"
    },
    {
        "number":"56131064" 
    },
    {
        "number":"56131063" 
    }
]
```

I post it from Postman like so:

[image]

I want to be able to print each number that I've posted individually using

```
echo $number;
```

Right now when I use the following it just prints the last number:

```
$number = $json['number'];
echo $number;
```

My function:

```
public function check_users_post()
{
    $json = $this->request->body;
    print_r($json);
    $this->response($json, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => 5613106
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => 56131064
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [number] => 56131063
        )

)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode a JSON String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543389/how-to-decode-a-json-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it done like this:

```
public function check_users_post()
{
    $json = $this->request->body;

    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator($json),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    $phone_numbers = "";

    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {

        } else {
            $phone_numbers = "$phone_numbers" . ", " . "$val";
        }
    }

    $phone_numbers = substr($phone_numbers, 2);
    $phone_numbers = "(" . $phone_numbers . ")";

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_number in $phone_numbers;");
    $result = $query->result();
    $this->response($result, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        $data = [ 'message' => 'No users returned'];
        $this->response($data, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        $this->response($result, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this generic iterator will help you.

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($json, TRUE)),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);


foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I used part of your answer to come up with my final answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
json_decode()
```

PHP built in function for decoding json back to PHP variable or array and then loop through each index and print number.

Comment: When I try json_decode($json) I receive: Message:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given. Am I not sending out a json through Postman already?

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans if you are doing that, you are already reading the JSON decoded, so post your complete code, and do `print_r($json);` to see what is inside `$json` because it seems is already an array...

Comment: @P0lT10n added my complete function

Comment: Ok. Here is tric: Please do not use json_decode(), just loop through array and access elements by using index. 

foreach($json as $item=> $val)
{
   echo $val;
}

Answer (score 0):

**Description**

First stringify your JSON, than use JSON_DECODE() function which gives you the array afterwards iterate on this array using foreach loop which will give you the each key which you want to echo.

**Code**

```
             $str = '[
                  {
                   "number":"5613106"
                  },
                  {
                   "number":"56131064"  
                  },
                  {
                   "number":"56131063"  
                  }
               ]';
            $array = json_decode($str, true);
            echo "<pre>";
            foreach ($array as $key => $key_value) { // then loop through it
                echo "<br>";
                echo $array[$key]['number'];
                echo "<br>";
           }
```

**Output**

```
5613106

56131064

56131063
```

Comment: How do I stringify my JSON?

Comment: you may test according to my answer now.